# Using sqldatareader in another sqldatareader

Tags: asp.net

I'm checking table to see if ID exists in table A if that ID exists insert it in table B but I also would like to check in table B if that ID number was not already inserted. But my issue is that I'm not able to combine all of that together. I'm not sure how to put a sqldatareader into another.

```
 SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("CreateID", con);
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("selectID", conn);
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SelectIDfromtableB", con);
 public SqlDataReader dr;
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    sessionCount++;
                    Session["Count"] = sessionCount;

                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@crate_box_no", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = id; 
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = user;
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date;
                }

                reader.Close();
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();     
            }                      
            else
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "MessagePopUp", "alert( Id number does not exist'); window.location.href = 'Return.aspx';", true);

            }
        }
        if (dr.Read())
         {
            lblError.Text = "Data was inserted before";                  
         }
         dr.Close();
```

Comment: `I'm not sure how to put a sqldatareader into another.` <= What is not working when you do this? Also you should share both queries, using a join you could probably accomplish what you need with a single query instead of having to run a second query for every item in the result from the 1st.

Comment: i'm getting the error message + it is inserting into the database. or I might get an error that i need to close the first sqldatareader but even after that it still doesn't do what I want

Comment: Well you would need to open a second Sql connection but it is difficult to say what you are doing if you do not share the actual code. Please see about including an [mcve].

Comment: your code is irrelevant to the question you are aksing

Comment: @Coding; what do you mean irrelevant? I'm actually using the code

Comment: You code seems missing, what is `dr`? where it is declared?

Comment: @Coding; my bad; I've added dr but is it possible to incorporate everytning

Comment: @Coding  can you assist

Comment: You cannot use dr.Read() unless you have a command associated with it.

Comment: yeah i did associate it with a command SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SelectIDfromtableB", con); dr=com.ExecuteReader(); is because I don't know how to incorporate everthing

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just do 2 queries? First one counting rows of id occurences, if greater 0 then count occurences in table b, if 0 continue?

Edit Example pseudo code:

```
command1 = "select id from tableA where id = toLookForId";
Define GridView1 and Gridview2;
Gridview1.datasource = sqldatareader.executenonquery(command1);
Gridview1.databind();
if gridview1.rows.count > 0 then
    command2 = "select id from tableB where id = toLookForId";
    Gridview2.datasource = sqlreader.executenonquery(command2);
    gridview2.databind();
    if gridview2.rows.count = 0 then
        //your code goes here
    else 
        //id exists so quit
        return;
    end if        
end if
```

Regards,

Maheshvara

Comment: can you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

You can minimize the code, use one connection for all the readers and one command, but you have to set the `CommandText` each time and clear the parameters if there were any. Use the `using` keyword to make sure your resources are disposed.

If there is anything you need to check in your first command, you can set a flag

```
using (var conn = GetTheConnection())
{
      conn.Open();

  //flag to check if id exists
  var idExists = false;

  var cmd= new SqlCommand("CreateID", conn );
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@crate_box_no", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = id; 

  using (var myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
  {
    if(myReader.Read())
    {
       idExists = true;
    }
  } 

  //clear parameters
  if (idExists) 
  {
      cmd.Parameters.Clear();
      cmd.commandText = "You 2nd SQL Script here"
      using (var myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
      } 
  }
}
```

Comment: how does the part about CreateID comes in

Comment: what do you mean? you can put your query or sp